# Не могу отправить фото используя pyrogram (telegram, python)

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Есть программа, которая должна отправлять картинку по запросу в telegram чат:

```python
from pyrogram import Client, filters
import test

app = Client('my_user_bot')

@app.on_message(filters.command("meme", prefixes=".") & filters.me)
def type(app, message):

    print(message['chat'])
    text = message.text.split(".meme ", maxsplit=1)[1]
    test.make_img(text)
    message.delete()
    app.send_photo(int(message['chat']['id']), 'img.png')
    print('da')


app.run()
```

По какой-то причине фото не отправляется, программа не выдает никаких ошибок.
Также строчка `print('da)` не выполняется,
то есть программа попросту останавливается на предыдущей строке.

Comment: А если вместо имени файла указать как объект, типа: `app.send_photo(int(message['chat']['id']), open('img.png', 'rb'))`?

Answer (score 0):

`filters.me` обозначает самого бота, а не вас. Проще говоря, бот ждёт команды от самого себя.

1. Узнайте ID своего аккаунта в Telegram (проще всего через [@userinfobot](https://t.me/userinfobot))
2. Используйте `filters.user(<ваш ID>)`

```py
from pyrogram import Client, filters
import test

app = Client('my_user_bot')


@app.on_message(filters.command("meme", prefixes=".") & filters.user(123456789))
def type(app, message):
    print(message.chat)
    text = message.text.split(".meme ", maxsplit=1)[1]
    test.make_img(text)
    message.delete()
    app.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'img.png')
    print('da')


app.run()
```

Также можно сделать [свой отдельный фильтр](https://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/create-filters):

```py
from pyrogram import Client, filters
import test


def func(_, __, message):
    return message.from_user.id == 123456789  # возвращает True, если именно вы 
                                              # отправили сообщение

is_author = filters.create(func)  # создание фильтра

app = Client('my_user_bot')


@app.on_message(filters.command("meme", prefixes=".") & is_author)  # использование
def type(app, message):
    print(message.chat)
    text = message.text.split(".meme ", maxsplit=1)[1]
    test.make_img(text)
    message.delete()
    app.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'img.png')
    print('da')


app.run()
```

Answer (score -1):

Лучше используйте библиотеку PyTelegramBotApi

```
import telebot
from requests import get

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["meme"])
def start(message):
  photo = open('/tmp/photo.png', 'rb')
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ТЕСТ")
  bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: При чём тут PyTelegramBotApi? Pyrogram - используется для работы с MTProto API, а PyTelegramBotApi - для работы с Bot API